# Glitches appear on facebook chat window when using Mac Book Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, screen

At the bottom of my Facebook chat, there are irritating glitches that I cannot unsee now.

The arrows point to the red box indicating the errors. I use the Chrome browser on Mavericks.

[image]

Is this common for 2013 Retina MacBook Pro?

Comment: Do you also have these glitches in Safari ?

Comment: No, there isn't any glitches in Safari.. but i like to use google Chrome

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? Try deactivating them

Comment: Do these glitches appear in the latest Chrome Canary?

Comment: Sorry everyone. Those glitches were back with the latest version of Chrome Canary.

Comment: Can any Mac book pro user tell me if they have similar glitches appearing in their facebook chat window?